# Storing information from switch statement into a variable?

Tags: c++, reference, switch-statement

I am trying to make a character customization program. I want to store the information received from the switch statement into storePlayerRace Variable. I am trying to pass that information as a reference. I don't know how if that's the right way of doing this. This problem is really bothering me since it should be so simple. Every time I run this the cout statement does not output any text to the screen. I want the race that was selected to output to the screen. Any related help is greatly appreciated! 
**I am trying to break the scope of the switch statement.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    string characterName(string x){
        return x;
    }
    string characterRace(string &x){
        return x;
    }


    int main()
    {

        string name;
        string storePlayerName;
        string storePlayerRace;

        int race;
        cout << "<------Character Creation------->" << endl;
        cout << "\n\n Enter Character name " << endl;
        getline(cin,name);
        storePlayerName = characterName(name);

        cout << "\n Select Race " << endl;
        cout << "1: White";
        cout << "\n2: Black\n";
        cin >> race;

        switch(race){
            case 1:
                {               
                    string white;
                    storePlayerRace = characterRace(white);

                }break;
            case 2: 
                {
                    string black;
                    storePlayerRace = characterRace(black);
                }break;
        }
        cout << storePlayerRace << endl;
        cout << "End of Program" << endl;
        getchar();
        system("PAUSE");
    }
```

Comment: You might want an `enum races {black, white}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string white;
string black;
```

These two lines just define empty strings with no text in them. I think you meant something like:

```
string white = "white";
string black = "black";
```

Also I'm not sure what your `characterRace()` function is really meant to accomplish, at the moment it's a no-op and so could be simplified to:

```
case 1:
    storePlayerRace = "white";
    break;
case 2:
    storePlayerRace = "black";
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialise your `string white` and `string black` variables within your switch statement.

EG:

```
string white = "white";
string black = "black";
```

Comment: No such thing a silly question. If you don't ask you don't learn :)